# Wrongly closed / on hold?

Tags: support

[Take a look at this question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/202955/79435) Why is it on hold? It has the question written there and it has a detailed code. There is also a lot of useful information and the OP clearly pointed out his problem and his question "What caused the crash?". Why is this question being on hold?

Comment: Please see here: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/how-do-i-ask-minecraft-questions

Comment: Crash questions, especially Minecraft questions, almost *always* never give enough information for us to solve the problem.  There is a minimal level of information we need, and a straight up crash dump rarely gives that information.

Comment: Is THAT considered *not enough info*? I mean, the OP provided what he/she did and how he/she came to this crash.

Comment: Based on the lack of reopen votes and further action from the asker, yeah, I'd say that's not enough information.